# Unable to set a selection on a JTextField after a NavigationFilter

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextfield

I managed to select my JTextField like that :

```
jtfNumTag.setSelectionStart(0);
jtfNumTag.setSelectionEnd(iMaxLenght);
```

but when I added a NavigationFilter on my JTextField, the select didn't work.
I could understand if my NavigationFilter prevented the selection to be done but I don't see why it would do that.

```
final int iMaxLenght = szValues[0].length();
NavigationFilter filter = new NavigationFilter() {
    public void setDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias) {
        if (dot >= iMaxLenght) {
            fb.setDot(iMaxLenght, bias);
        } else {
            fb.setDot(dot, bias);
        }
     }
    public void moveDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias) {
        if (dot >= iMaxLenght) {
            fb.setDot(iMaxLenght, bias);
        } else {
            fb.setDot(dot, bias);
        }
    }
};
jtfNumTag.setNavigationFilter(filter);

jtfNumTag.setSelectionStart(0);
jtfNumTag.setSelectionEnd(iMaxLenght);
```

Thank you in advance to explain me what I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `fb.setDot`, you should probably call `fb.moveDot()` in `NavigationFilter.moveDot` implementation. Otherwise the caret will not move at all. For example:

```
public void moveDot(NavigationFilter.FilterBypass fb, int dot, Position.Bias bias) {
    if (dot >= iMaxLenght) {
        fb.moveDot(iMaxLenght, bias);
    } else {
        fb.moveDot(dot, bias);
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact moveDot was useless. It worked without this method. But your changes work too. Thank you!